# Arch partition detected but not added to boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a triple-boot system with Windows, Ubuntu and Arch Linux. I have successfully dual-booted Ubuntu and Windows, and I have set up an installation of the arch in another partition, but I am not able to get a boot entry for Arch from the boot menu. I have run:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

And the command outputs `"Found Arch Linux on /dev/sda7"`, but no entry is added to the menu nor the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Please advise. I am trying to add the Arch entry to the Ubuntu menu since I have been a long time user of Ubuntu, but I am a newbie to Arch.

Below is the results generated by boot-info-script:

```
                      Boot Info Script 0.76      [13 April 2017]


    ============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Windows 7/8/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Windows 7/8/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       NTFS
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /tmp/BootInfo-Tds9bPFc/sda3: unknown filesystem type ''.

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       NTFS
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda4 has 
                       803742856 sectors, but according to the info from 
                       fdisk, it has 803743743 sectors.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Arch Linux
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /syslinux.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/HashTool.efi /efi/boot/loader.efi

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1 1,000,215,215 1,000,215,215  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition  Attrs   Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1      R          2,048       923,647       921,600 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda2               923,648     1,126,399       202,752 EFI System partition
/dev/sda3             1,126,400     1,159,167        32,768 Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows)
/dev/sda4             1,159,168   804,902,911   803,743,744 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda5           804,902,912   867,403,775    62,500,864 Swap partition (Linux)
/dev/sda6           867,403,776   929,904,639    62,500,864 Data partition (Linux)
/dev/sda7           929,904,640 1,000,214,527    70,309,888 Data partition (Linux)

Attributes: R=Required, N=No Block IO, B=Legacy BIOS Bootable, +=More bits set

Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1                   1 1,953,525,167 1,953,525,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition  Attrs   Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sdb1                 2,048 1,953,523,711 1,953,521,664 Data partition (Linux)

Attributes: R=Required, N=No Block IO, B=Legacy BIOS Bootable, +=More bits set

Drive: sdc _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sdc: 14.7 GiB, 15728640000 bytes, 30720000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdc1                   1 4,294,967,295 4,294,967,295  ee GPT

/dev/sdc1 ends after the last sector of /dev/sdc

GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition  Attrs   Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sdc1                 2,048    30,719,966    30,717,919 Data partition (Windows/Linux)

Attributes: R=Required, N=No Block IO, B=Legacy BIOS Bootable, +=More bits set

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop1                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop10                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop11                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop12                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop13                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop14                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop15                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop2                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop3                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop4                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop5                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop6                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop7                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop8                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop9                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        2C4AF6E54AF6AAAA                       ntfs       Recovery
/dev/sda2        18F7-3E33                              vfat       
/dev/sda3                                                          
/dev/sda4        CE13000512FFEFF7                       ntfs       
/dev/sda5        d233d512-fbba-44f9-aff6-046b6703df19   swap       
/dev/sda6        b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5   ext4       
/dev/sda7        feaa6bde-b426-4d73-a279-5daf052173ba   ext4       Arch
/dev/sdb1        5d00895e-ac24-4e73-864c-a52829b2c35f   ext4       
/dev/sdc1        AC98-19EC                              vfat       ARCH_202001

========================= "ls -l /dev/disk/by-id" output: ======================

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 29 23:53 ata-ADATA_SU760_2J4520138012 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 29 23:53 ata-ADATA_SU760_2J4520138012-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 29 23:53 ata-ADATA_SU760_2J4520138012-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 29 23:53 ata-ADATA_SU760_2J4520138012-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 29 23:53 ata-ADATA_SU760_2J4520138012-part4 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 29 23:53 ata-ADATA_SU760_2J4520138012-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 29 23:53 ata-ADATA_SU760_2J4520138012-part6 -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 29 23:53 ata-ADATA_SU760_2J4520138012-part7 -> ../../sda7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 29 23:53 ata-Samsung_SSD_860_EVO_1TB_S5JANE0MB04353M -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 29 23:53 ata-Samsung_SSD_860_EVO_1TB_S5JANE0MB04353M-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 29 23:53 usb-SMI_USB_DISK-0:0 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 29 23:53 usb-SMI_USB_DISK-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 29 23:53 wwn-0x5002538e09b98170 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 29 23:53 wwn-0x5002538e09b98170-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 29 23:53 wwn-0x5707c18100872624 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 29 23:53 wwn-0x5707c18100872624-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 29 23:53 wwn-0x5707c18100872624-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 29 23:53 wwn-0x5707c18100872624-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 29 23:53 wwn-0x5707c18100872624-part4 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 29 23:53 wwn-0x5707c18100872624-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 29 23:53 wwn-0x5707c18100872624-part6 -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 29 23:53 wwn-0x5707c18100872624-part7 -> ../../sda7

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda2        /boot/efi                vfat       (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda6        /                        ext4       (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdb1        /home                    ext4       (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdc1        /media/pipemon/ARCH_202001 vfat       (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)


=========================== sda6/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt6'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 10 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=1
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5
    fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-28-generic root=UUID=b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-28-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-28-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.3.0-28-generic-advanced-b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.3.0-28-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-28-generic root=UUID=b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-28-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-28-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.3.0-28-generic-recovery-b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.3.0-28-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-28-generic root=UUID=b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-28-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-26-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.3.0-26-generic-advanced-b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.3.0-26-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-26-generic root=UUID=b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-26-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-26-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.3.0-26-generic-recovery-b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.3.0-26-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-26-generic root=UUID=b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-26-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.0-23-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.0.0-23-generic-advanced-b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.0.0-23-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic root=UUID=b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.0-23-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.0.0-23-generic-recovery-b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.0.0-23-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic root=UUID=b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-18F7-3E33' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  18F7-3E33
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 18F7-3E33
    fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}

set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda6/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=b1e9c50c-53dd-4ba4-9c32-2d7f8b9ce9b5 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=18F7-3E33  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=5d00895e-ac24-4e73-864c-a52829b2c35f /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=d233d512-fbba-44f9-aff6-046b6703df19 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda6: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

 422.108402252 = 453.235445760  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             2
 415.407222748 = 446.040109056  boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic                  2
 423.603244781 = 454.840520704  boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-26-generic                  1
 425.095432281 = 456.442744832  boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-28-generic                  1
 425.095432281 = 456.442744832  vmlinuz                                        1
 423.603244781 = 454.840520704  vmlinuz.old                                    1
 424.157814026 = 455.435984896  boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic               2
 424.281719208 = 455.569027072  boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-26-generic               2
 425.250030518 = 456.608743424  boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-28-generic               6
 425.250030518 = 456.608743424  initrd.img                                     6
 424.281719208 = 455.569027072  initrd.img.old                                 2

=============================== sda7/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Static information about the filesystems.
# See fstab(5) for details.

# <file system> <dir> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
# UUID=feaa6bde-b426-4d73-a279-5daf052173ba LABEL=Arch
/dev/sda7               /           ext4        rw,relatime 0 1

# UUID=18F7-3E33 LABEL=BootEfi
/dev/sda2       /boot/efi       vfat        umask=0077      0 1

# UUID=5d00895e-ac24-4e73-864c-a52829b2c35f
/dev/sdb1               /home       ext4        rw,relatime 0 2

# UUID=d233d512-fbba-44f9-aff6-046b6703df19 LABEL=Swap
/dev/sda5       none            swap        sw              0 0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

============================== sdc1/syslinux.cfg: ==============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

================= sdc1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux: ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown MBR on /dev/sdc

00000000  41 4b 45 4f fc 31 c0 8e  d8 be 31 7c e8 13 00 be  |AKEO.1....1|....|
00000010  5c 7c e8 0d 00 be 31 7c  e8 07 00 be 87 7c e8 01  |\|....1|.....|..|
00000020  00 f4 ac 3c 00 74 09 b4  0e bb 07 00 cd 10 eb f2  |...<.t..........|
00000030  c3 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a  2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a  |.***************|
00000040  2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a  2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a  |****************|
00000050  2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a  2a 0d 0a 00 2a 2a 2a 20  |*********...*** |
00000060  45 52 52 4f 52 3a 20 4c  45 47 41 43 59 20 42 4f  |ERROR: LEGACY BO|
00000070  4f 54 20 4f 46 20 55 45  46 49 20 4d 45 44 49 41  |OT OF UEFI MEDIA|
00000080  20 2a 2a 2a 0d 0a 00 0d  0a 54 68 69 73 20 64 72  | ***.....This dr|
00000090  69 76 65 20 63 61 6e 20  6f 6e 6c 79 20 62 6f 6f  |ive can only boo|
000000a0  74 20 69 6e 20 55 45 46  49 20 6d 6f 64 65 2e 0d  |t in UEFI mode..|
000000b0  0a 49 74 20 63 61 6e 20  6e 6f 74 20 62 6f 6f 74  |.It can not boot|
000000c0  20 69 6e 20 42 49 4f 53  2f 4c 65 67 61 63 79 20  | in BIOS/Legacy |
000000d0  6d 6f 64 65 2e 0d 0a 0d  0a 49 66 20 79 6f 75 20  |mode.....If you |
000000e0  77 61 6e 74 20 74 6f 20  62 6f 6f 74 20 74 68 69  |want to boot thi|
000000f0  73 20 64 72 69 76 65 20  69 6e 20 42 49 4f 53 2f  |s drive in BIOS/|
00000100  4c 65 67 61 63 79 20 6d  6f 64 65 2c 20 79 6f 75  |Legacy mode, you|
00000110  0d 0a 73 68 6f 75 6c 64  20 72 65 63 72 65 61 74  |..should recreat|
00000120  65 20 69 74 20 69 6e 20  52 75 66 75 73 20 75 73  |e it in Rufus us|
00000130  69 6e 67 20 74 68 65 20  66 6f 6c 6c 6f 77 69 6e  |ing the followin|
00000140  67 20 73 65 74 74 69 6e  67 73 3a 0d 0a 2a 20 50  |g settings:..* P|
00000150  61 72 74 69 74 69 6f 6e  20 73 63 68 65 6d 65 20  |artition scheme |
00000160  2d 3e 20 4d 42 52 0d 0a  2a 20 54 61 72 67 65 74  |-> MBR..* Target|
00000170  20 73 79 73 74 65 6d 20  2d 3e 20 42 49 4f 53 2e  | system -> BIOS.|
00000180  2e 2e 0d 0a 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000190  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001c0  02 00 ee fe ff 77 01 00  00 00 ff ff ff ff 00 00  |.....w..........|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that there had to be a separate /boot partition that is mounted to both Ubuntu and Arch for it to be discoverable by both operating systems. After changing that, I could generate a grub menu for Arch using `grub-mkconfig`. Then I added the generated grub as a custom menu entry to the Ubuntu operating system configured in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, that way when there is a kernel change in Ubuntu and the grub gets updated, there will allways be a backup boot entry for Arch.